# Possible vulnerability within my application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Apologies if this is in the wrong category. I'm currently developing and application in ASP, due to my inexperience with ASP I'm worried about vulnerabilities that a user can exploit.

My application is being coded from scratch, no templates used or defaults from Visual Studio, completely blank projects. The user is greeted with a login page where depending on there user access in active directory depends on which pages the user can access.

The exploit I'm worried about is if the user will be able to commit a directory traversal and access a page in which they're not allowed to access and change critical information.

I'm afraid my inexperience has caught up with me. Could someone explain to me how I could limit the access to the user or, If I'm over thinking the process, correct me? Constructive criticism is accepted.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm thinking this question is _too broad_ and may be flagged as such.

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried wording it the best I could, I believe I've found the answers I've been looking for, thank you bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft does try to help protect your application through their defaults, so if you're running in IIS, make sure the user the application pool is running under only has write access to the folders it needs to write into.

This is a very open-ended question and depends on many factors such as version of .net, server OS/IIS version, other handlers installed, etc. But a good start is to review the OWASP Top 10:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project#OWASP_Top_10_for_2013

Here's a list of some automated tools you can use for testing your implementation:
https://geekflare.com/online-scan-website-security-vulnerabilities/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'll further investigate with the links you've provided, many thanks